# Merge a list of DataFrames based on string in a column and then convert this to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe, dictionary

**Task Description**

I am wanting to merge a list of DataFrames based on string in a column (Country) and then convert this to a dictionary and have the Country column as the key and the merged DataFrames as the values. Example of the data:

**List of country names**

```
country_names = ['ITA', USA', 'UK', 'ARG']
```

**List of DataFrames named `df_countries`**

```
df_countries[0]

  index   Date      A   B   C  Country     
    1   2019-12-31  x   y   z    ITA
    2   2019-12-30  x   y   z    ITA    

df_countries[1]

  index   Date      A   B   C  Country     
    1   2019-12-31  x   y   z    ITA
    2   2019-12-30  x   y   z    ITA    

df_countries[2]

  index   Date      A   B   C  Country     
    1   2019-12-31  x   y   z    USA
    2   2019-12-30  x   y   z    USA    

df_countries[3]

  index   Date      A   B   C  Country     
    1   2019-12-31  x   y   z    ARG
    2   2019-12-30  x   y   z    ARG
```

I would like, for example, ITA to look like the following once merged and then a dictionary created from this with ITA as the key etc. :

```
  index   Date      A   B   C  Country     
    1   2019-12-31  x   y   z    ITA
    2   2019-12-30  x   y   z    ITA       
    3   2019-12-31  x   y   z    ITA
    4   2019-12-30  x   y   z    ITA
```

Any help would be super!

Comment: You could merge all the dataframes with `pd.concat`, then select the rows matching the country and assign them as a new dataframe.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @AMC, JohannesAck solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @oceanbeach96 That doesn’t mean that the question cannot be further improved though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit elaborated from my comment:
You could first merge all dataframes with `pd.concat()`, then select the matching rows and create new dataframes from them:

```
merged_frame = pd.concat(df_countries)
country_dict = {}
for country in country_names:
    country_dict[country] = merged_frame[merged_frame['Country'] == country]
```

Optionally you can also call `country_dict[country].reset_index()` to fix the indices of the new frames.